# Addition Of Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

Please go through the following loops:

I am especially confused about the first loop,

1st loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", ptr + i);
}
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    sum = sum + (*(ptr + i));
}
```

2nd loop:

```
int *x ;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    x = ptr + sizeof(i);
    scanf("%d",x );
}
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{ 
    x = ptr + sizeof(i) ;
    sum = sum + (*x);
}
```

Why do entering the elements in the array by using malloc 
using the above loops give the same result ?
Why are the first and second loop giving equal or right result ?

why are (ptr + i) and ptr + sizeof(i) working in same waY?

Entire program is

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#define NULL 0

int main()

{
    int *ptr;
    int i, n, sum = 0 ;
    float avg ;
    printf("Enter the number of elements you want to store in the array.");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    ptr = (int *) malloc( n * sizeof(int)) ; /*Dynamic Memory allocation*/
    if(ptr == NULL)
     {
        printf("The required amount of memory is not available. ");
        getch();
        exit(0);                                                                            
     }

    else
        {
        printf("Enter the elements\n");
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                scanf("%d", ptr + i);
            }
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                sum = sum + (*(ptr + i));
            }

        printf("\nThe sum of %d elements entered is = %d",n , sum );
        avg = sum / n ;
        printf("\nThe average of %d number of the array is %f", n, avg);
        }

        printf("\n");
        getch();

}
```

Comment: How is `ptr` declared?

Comment: `x` is declared as an `int` and you are trying to dereference it.

Comment: int *x ;
I am sorry I didn't enter the entire program

Comment: The main confusion is the last sentence in the question.

Comment: You _must_ post the definition of `ptr` to get a clear answer.  It is important for this question.

Comment: The answer to that question is because, in the second loop, you are storing and reading data the same way. So even there are gaps between the data, it doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: `sizeof(i)` is a constant value.

Comment: Those two loops are nowhere *near* equivalent. `x = ptr + sizeof(i);` will result in the same pointer unless `ptr` changes (which it doesn't in your code); the value of `i` is irrelevant in the latter code, and entirely relevant in the former.

Comment: In the second loop, you are using `ptr[0]` `ptr[4]` ...`ptr[n*4]` for both `scanf` and `sum`.

Comment: @ott Why are ptr + i and ptr + sizeof(i) equivalent?

Comment: @AkankshaSingh They are only equivalent if `i == sizeof(i)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig but both the loops are giving the same results. Why?

Comment: Prove it. If they are, then it is probably undefined behaviour. You need to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AkankshaSingh Post a **complete** [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows that. Until then, it didn't happen.

Comment: You're also doing integer division, which will cause truncation. Wiki/google "integer truncation sum" problem.

Answer (score 4):

> why are (ptr + i) and ptr + sizeof(i) working in same waY?

They are not.  In the first example, you read `n` values into an array (storing them in succesive elements), and then add those `n` values.  In the second example, you read `n` values and store them all in the *same* element of the array (overwriting the previous element), so you end up with an array that is mostly uninitialized, but has one element set to the last value read.  You then add that element to itself `n` times.

So you *might* end up with the same sum in both cases (for example, if your numbers are 1,3,2), or you might not.

Comment: But why is ptr + i loading the elements at the right position? isn't ptr supposed to store the address and doesn't the ptr + i means that the adress is incremented by i times ?

Comment: Because `ptr+i` computes the address of `i`th element of the array.  So `*(ptr + i)` is the same as `p[i]`.  That's the same thing as 'the address incremented i times' -- adding is equivalent to incrementing multiple times.